# CSSStyleSheet.replaceSync nodejs implementation

Tags: css, node.js

I'm searching for thing that will allow me to use CSSStyleSheet `replaceSync` method in Node.js

Node.js doesn't have DOM implemented inside, so all JavaScript that is characteristic for web design doesn't exist in Node.js

Also I tested these popular libraries, and none of them correctly implemented the `replaceSync` method (some of them even don't have `replaceSync` method and others `replaceSync` method is buggy - often parses the CSS wrong).

- jsdom
- cssstyle
- cssom

Seems like there is no library that correctly supports `replaceSync` method in Node.js

Is there a way to easily implement the `replaceSync` method by my own?